# Buttons in a subview not working with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui, swift3

I have this subview declared here:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationBarView: View {
        
    @State private var showingMenu = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {print("test")}, label: {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            })
            Spacer()
            Text("SAT Daily")
                .font(.custom("Nunito-Bold", size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("test")
                }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {print("test1")}, label: {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            })
        }.onTapGesture {
            print("bruh")
        }
    }
}
```

I call this view in my homepage to display it (the view above is a header):

```swift
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color(UIColor(red: 0.067, green: 0.137, blue: 0.322, alpha: 1))
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    VStack() {
                        
                        NavigationBarView()
                            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                            .padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
                            .background(Color(UIColor(red: 0.024, green: 0.092, blue: 0.267, alpha: 1).cgColor))
                            .zIndex(1)
                        
                        ScrollView(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.vertical/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, showsIndicators: false, content: {
```

If I click any of the buttons that print the statements correspond to it does not print. How do I fix this?

The profile icon and menu icon are the buttons that don’t work. The header (with the logo SAT Daily) is the sub view that is being called on my main page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qvo1.png

Comment: It's working for me. Can you show full code for your homepage (including where you put `navigationBarHidden`)? Nice app btw

Comment: Sure thing and thanks! Here: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/852639201744650240/853833323095654440/ContentView.swift

Comment: I ran it and the buttons are clickable...

Comment: Yeah loads of people seem to be saying its working and its confusing me even more. It could be that I am testing on my phone. I will test it on the simulator and find out.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the buttons on the simulator(not in Preview), it will print out. (Your code runs fine, when I run it)

[image]

Comment: I try clicking it on the app on my phone could that be the issue? and if so how do you suggest to fix it? I test it on my iPhone xr.

Comment: @meep I tested just now with [iPhone 12 in Xcode12 simulator] and [iPhone 12 actual device & iOS15 in Xcode 13 Beta], and I could check the print in the console of both. Unfortunately, it seems difficult to find out what the problem is. It's annoying, but simple way is to try reinstalling Xcode.